# Trigger/Notification on quote template creation?

Tags: apex, trigger, community, quote-template

I am working on a project that will require me to auto-populate a pick list field with the current active quote templates. When a new quote template is created, the pick list should be populated with the new quote template name to be available for selection.

Is there any way to create a trigger with this behavior? I know quote templates cannot be accessed directly using APEX but I am wondering if there is a way to know a new quote template has been created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. [It's not supported by the Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm), so you can't even write a job to monitor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer-- I had a feeling this was the case.